# plotting sound signal using matlab and gui

Tags: matlab, user-interface

when i'm running this code it gave me nothing but the following error

> matlab.graphics.internal.figfile.FigFile/read>@(hObject,eventdata)untitled('pushbutton2_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject)) 
>   Error while evaluating UIControl Callback

here's my code

```
function varargout = untitled(varargin)
% UNTITLED MATLAB code for untitled.fig
%      UNTITLED, by itself, creates a new UNTITLED or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = UNTITLED returns the handle to a new UNTITLED or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      UNTITLED('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in UNTITLED.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      UNTITLED('Property','Value',...) creates a new UNTITLED or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before untitled_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to untitled_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help untitled

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 16-Dec-2016 17:10:11

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @untitled_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @untitled_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before untitled is made visible.
function untitled_OpeningFcn(hObject, ~, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to untitled (see VARARGIN)




% Choose default command line output for untitled
bushbutton1()
bushbutton2()

% Update handles structure
handles.output = hObject;




guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes untitled wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = untitled_OutputFcn(~, ~, handles) 
varargout{1} = handles.output;


% --- Executes on button press in bushbutton1.
function bushbutton1_Callback(hobject,eventdata,handles)
global speech
x = audiorecorder(16000,16,1);
recordblocking(x,3);
speech = getaudiodata(x,'double');


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
axes(handles.axes1)
plot(handles.speech)
```

is there any suggestions, thanks.

Comment: Which line is producing that error?

Comment: line 42 @GameOfThrows

Answer (score 0):

You didn't save `speech` into the `handles` struct. You need to do so using [`guidata`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html)

```
function bushbutton1_Callback(hobject,eventdata,handles)
    x = audiorecorder(16000,16,1);
    recordblocking(x,3);
    handles.speech = getaudiodata(x,'double');

    % Save the updated handles struct
    guidata(hobject, handles);
end

function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    axes(handles.axes1)
    plot(handles.speech)
end
```

or just use `speech` since you've already defined it as a global variable. Note that this is less preferable since the usage of `global` variables can lead to many issues.

```
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    gloabl speech
    plot(speech)
end
```

Comment: @user3474341 What's the error? Also which one did you try?

Comment: @user3474341 Also you are pushing the record button first, right?

Comment: @user3474341 What is the error. Also type `dbstop if error` in the command window so that MATLAB will place a breakpoint when it encounters and error and you can provide more information

Comment: it gave me window with errors like error using feval

Comment: gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:}); and also that error

Comment: @user3474341 Neither of those are helpful. Please put a debugging breakpoint inside of the callback so you can see what the issue is.